# Render only at index 0 and 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have this code

```
{(type === 'NEW') 
          && (index === 0)
          && <hr className={styles.hr}/>}
{(type === 'NEW') 
          && (index === 3)
          && <hr />}
```

My question is, how can I combine them to be just one expression which render that hr element only at index 0 and 3 ?
I tried to combine them like  `.. && (index === 0) && (index === 3) && <hr />` but it's not working because this code it's within a map loop closure.. hope I'm coherent. So if anyone knows how to help me, any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```js
{
  type === "NEW" && (index === 0 || index === 3) && <hr />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could use

```
{ 
  type === 'NEW' && [0, 3].includes(index) && 
    <hr />
}
```